# IE9 Jquery backbone fetch does not work

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, internet-explorer-9, fetch, jquery-deferred

I have a fully functional backbone js application. In my controller, I retrieve my model from api through chained when.apply function calls. For example,

```
          $.when.apply($, [<<array of deferred async calls>>]).done(function () {
              <<Code to be executed after all deferred calls complete>>
              });
```

This code has been working in latest firefox, chrome and IE10 browsers, but not in IE9. IE9 has not thrown any errors, but I see no calls made for loading the model data in network tab. Therefore the code to be executed after the call completes are not hit as well.

When searching for this issue I ran into this post. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply
The post says,

> Note: Most browsers, including Chrome 14 and Internet Explorer 9, still do not accept array-like objects and will throw an exception.

Is there a way around this without overhauling my existing code, which is a lot?

EDIT: After @Beetroot's comment below, it seems like backbone's fetch is to blame, which is used within the when.apply.

```
      r = { method: 'get', body: { userId: loggedInUser } };

      $.when.apply($, [employee.fetch(r), department.fetch(r)]).done(function () {
          <<Code to be executed after all deferred calls complete>>
          });
```

Again, when researching this issue, there are posts in SO like [Backbone fetch() fails for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240932/backbone-fetch-fails-for-ie), that suggest changing the fetch function to make it work in IE9. As mentioned above, we have hundreds of fetches in our application currently and it will set us back significantly if I have to rewrite these fetches. Is there any other way to fix this issue?

Comment: Show how you created and are using the *array*.

Comment: The code you have posted looks fine. The bug is almost certainly in (or arises from) one or more of the async processes whose promises are in the array passed to `.when()`.

Comment: Hmm @Beetroot-Beetroot, may be you have point. Inside the when.apply, I pass backbone collection's fetch calls. For example, 
`[Employee.fetch(r), Department.fetch(r)]`
where r has arguments to denote whether it is get call with additional parameters.

Comment: I just re-read the question and noticed the "array-like" proviso. First thing you need to check is that the object passed to `.when()` is indeed an array. You can use jQuery's [.makeArray(...)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) to ensure that it is indeed an array.

Comment: Yes - there is a check that exists to ensure that before the code is executed. Again, based on your comment, I have edited my post to indicate that the backbone's .fetch calls is the source of the problem.

Comment: Does both `fetch` calls work outside of `when`? Also, I don't think it's necessary to pass `method: 'get'` to the fetch call and AFAIK there is no option `body` anywhere in [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) so unless you have some custom code inside `fetch` it is very likely that your `body` parameter is being ignored.

Comment: Also, what's the version of your `Backbone` and `jQuery`? According to this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/ you can just pass  multiple xhr objects to it anyway so no need for `apply` really.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. 

Backbone.js version is 1.0.0 and jQuery version is 1.8.3. The backbone fetch function has not been customized in our application and works perfectly with the body parameters. It converts them into get parameters appropriately and sends the call over to the URL. 

The fetch does not work outside of when in IE9 but works in other browsers either inside or outside.

Answer (score 1):

I finally spoke to somebody in MS support and they gave me this workaround in IE 9.

1. Open IE9 and navigate to ‘Settings -> Internet Options’
2. Click on ‘Security’ tab. Choose ‘Internet’.
3. Click on ‘Custom level’.
4. Find a setting called ‘Access data sources across domains’ and choose enable.
5. Click okay. Refresh the app and try to login again.

This works for me now in IE9. In IE10 and above even if that setting is disabled, the calls continue to work. I am guessing it has something to do with the underlying ajax call that is made through backbone sync, which uses XMLHTTPRequest in all modern browsers and is unable to do that in IE9 and below.